# Why does my MFC application get uninstalled without giving a message even when it is open/running?

Tags: c++, mfc, runtime, uninstallation

I have an MFC application. When I want to uninstall it while it is open/running, the program gets smoothly uninstalled without producing a warning message (like: the program is running, please close it before continuing uninstallation procedure). The problem occurs in a fresh Windows 8 OS. It does not occur in a Windows 7 OS in which Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 is installed. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: From my point of view it is a bug, that the installer doesn't ask when the program is running. And the behavior of Windows 8 is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you indicating that the installer I have created using MFC has a bug? Then what should I do to avoid the problem?

Comment: No! I don't think it is the installer. It may be in the MSI core that the program is closed without dialog on Win7, and Win8 asks... I don't see any options that you can control this with the installer.

Answer (score 0):

As I statet in a comment: I think Win8 behaves correctly when it asks for closing the running application.

As a workaround: Write your own Custom Action in you MSI installer. This custom action can search for your application and send a message to it to force it to close... maybe WM_CLOSE is sufficient and if you provided your own [window class name](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196354/Provide-Your-Custom-Class-Name-to-your-MFC-Applica) for it finding it is easy.

Comment: Thanks. I think I should go for writing a custom application.

Comment: Not custom application. I mean custom action in the your MSI: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368066(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I created the installer in visual studio following normal procedure. I run my application. Task manager is showing it. I keep it open/running, and go to uninstall the application. But, windows (in which visual studio is not installed) does not show fileinuse dialog. I have checked the problem in a fresh windows 7 machine in which visual studio is not installed. The problem still arises. So its not a problem of different os. Does any extra package is installed during visual studio installation which helps showing the fileinuse dialog?

Comment: Read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2006/12/11/windows-installer-and-restart-manager-msi-files-in-use-v2.aspx